# Not getting click event on parent recyclerview's item in nested recyclerview situation. How to get for both recyclerviews?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This is the ui design

```
Parent RecyclerView-> cardview items-> Child RecyclerView-> custom layout items
```

Requirement is that there has to be single selection in this nested recyclerview situation.I am able to get the position of the selected child inside the nested recyclerview but I also want to know the position of the parent recyclerview child inside which nested recyclerview is present. Looks like parent recyclerview is passing down the click events to the children of its nested recyclerview. Please suggest how can I achieve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to manually bubble up an event, the child in the child recycler view gets the onClickListener, it attaches some information, passes it up to its parent (child recyclerview), and then child recyclerview can attach itself and pass it to the main parent.

The main Parent has to pass in a callback, and the same needs to be done by the child recyclerView.

The code may look something like this:

```kotlin
    class MainParent {
        val list = mutableListOf<ChildParent>()
        private val mainParentCallbackImpl = object : MainParentCallback {
            override fun childParentPressed(childParent: ChildParent) {
                //do whatever you need to do
            }
        }
        init {
            list.add(ChildParent(mainParentCallbackImpl))
        }

        interface MainParentCallback {
            fun childParentPressed(childParent: ChildParent)
        }
    }
    
    class ChildParent(private val parentCallback: MainParent.MainParentCallback) {
        val list = mutableListOf<Child>()
        private val childParentCallbackImpl = object : ChildParentCallback {
            override fun childPressed(child: Child) {
                //do whatever you need to do first
                parentCallback.childParentPressed(this@ChildParent)
            }
        }

        init {
            list.add(Child(childParentCallbackImpl))
        }

        interface ChildParentCallback {
            fun childPressed(child: Child)
        }
    }

    class Child(private val childParentCallback: ChildParent.ChildParentCallback) :
        View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            //do whatever you need to do first
            childParentCallback.childPressed(this)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was thinking on similar lines now. Have to try the solution though. Thanks.

Comment: Oh I was just thinking. I actually need the position of the parent recyclerview child which was clicked. I wonder if children inside child recyclerview have this info(position of its parent inside child recyclerview). Only then it makes sense to pass this info up the hierarchy. @Mohammed Abdul Bari

Comment: the easiest way would be to pass in the index, to the child, because the child would have no clue where it is in the list. If you don't want to that then when you get the child back you will have to iterate over the list the parent is holding, and do an equals. I would go for the index-based approach, rather than passing the child you can pass back the index, by making a simple change to the callback in the example

Comment: Sounds like a solution. I will update here after trying this approach.